# How can you detect that instances from different WMI Classes are the same?

Tags: wmi, wql

If I have two different classes for example `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` and `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` can I somehow figure out if they return same instances?

In my example I know they return data for the same instance and if I select Name from those 2 classes I can get instance identifiers. But can I detect via WQL or something similar if two classes return data for the same instances?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which WMI classes you want. There isn't a general way to do it for all WMI classes. Some have the relationship built while others do not. In the case for the performance counters and the raw vs formatted, yes the relationship exists but you need to query the class qualifier "AutoCook_RawClass".

For example class Win32_PerfFormatted_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk has a AutoCook_RawClass of Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk.

Alternatively, thought i'm not 100% sure it's always the case, I do believe that for the Win32_Perf stuff a simple string replacement of "Formatted" to "Raw" and vice versa will get you what you need.